# Firebase transaction

Tags: firebase, angularfire

My Problem:

User can create a new group, the group will have  incremental ID.

I want an incremental ID instead of a push ID because I want the ID can be used after(e.x. users can search the group by inputting the group id).So I used transaction to do this. I write some code and it works good (Thanks stackoverflow!)

when I test by myself but I am not sure if it is right when collision happens.Please have a look.

```
 var setGroupNumber = function() {
      //increment the number by 1 
      return $firebase(groupRef.child('info').child('groupNumber'))
        .$transaction(function(number) {
          if (!number) return 1;
          if (number < 0) return;
          return number + 1
        });
    }
var create = function(user_id, photoStr, name) {
  setGroupNumber().then(function(snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot) {
      console.log('transcation is aborted');
    }
    var group_id = snapshot.val() + 1000;

    $firebase(groupRef.child('group').child(group_id))
      .$set({
        photoURL: photoStr,
        group_id: group_id,
        user_id: user_id,
        name: name,
        members: {},
        created_time: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      })
      .then(function() {
        $firebase(groupRef.child('group').child(group_id).child('members').child(user_id)).$set(true);
      })
  })
}
```

It does the work for me now, but I have two questions.

1. Is this a proper way to do this(i.e. the group id will not duplicate)?
2. In my code,I do a lot of things after setGroupNumber(such as updating the user's database,etc.not shown here), does this mean that other user who wants to create the group will wait until all these are done?

Thank you for your time:)

Comment: Seems simpler to just have the transaction start returning values at 1000 instead of 1, and skip adding 1000 to the group id in another method--less coupling. Transactions are the correct way to get this done. There are way too many non-specific questions here for the StackOverflow format. Pick exactly one problem to solve at a time. Keep in mind that this is a Q&A, not a discussion form.

Comment: @Kato Thanks Kato, you solved the main question I wanted to ask and I edited my question, only on the transaction part.so it may be useful for any person who encounters the transaction problem:)